# How do I save file with Windows 1250 encoding in php

Tags: php, encoding

I have a problem saving a file with the proper encoding. I set the header, convert the text, and save the file, but when I open it with PhpStorm, it says the encoding is UTF-8 instead of Windows-1250. It is important for me that the encoding is set to Windows-1250 because I need to load it into an archaic program that breaks characters if the encoding is different

```
$content = "Wiść mośc koa kskzź";

$content = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1250", $content);

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1250');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="order.ext_"');

echo $content;
exit;
```

Comment: The file data is just a stream of arbitrary bytes, there is nothing to denote what the encoding is. The headers tell _your browser_, but those have no bearing on the file that gets saved and then opened elsewhere. Inspect the _actual data_ to see if it's correct, not whatever some random text editor think it might be.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: This should work, as long as PhpStorm is saving your PHP code in UTF-8 (you can see that in the status bar, as I guess you already do with the resulting attachment).